# Applying a filter to all arguments of cat

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a list of files on a server, let's say matching the pattern `http://example.com/abcd-{0..99}.zip`.

I want to download, then decompress all these files (they're just zipped text, with one file in each .zip), concatenate them into a single stream, then pipe it into a different program.
I know to download them, it's best to use curl, and to unzip, I can use funzip, but funzip only takes a single .zip as a parameter.

Is bash capable of doing this painlessly (if so, how?), or should I just give up and do this in python?

Comment: I am not sure about python, but you can do it using bash ( as you said using curl and unzip ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script I ended up writing to do this is:

```
echo http://example.com/some-data{0..799}.csv.zip | xargs -n1 -P8 ./download-file
```

and the contents of download-file are:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$(basename $1 .zip).xz
wget -O- $1 | funzip | nice -n5 xz -z9 > $NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say why you wanted to use `curl` and `funzip`. I think for your purposes `wget` and `unzip` would work better. Say your list of files is in the file *filelist*. Then to download all those files, execute

```
wget -i filelist
```

Then to unzip those files and pipe them into some program, execute

```
unzip -p 'abcd-*.zip' | program
```

Note that you must quote the zip file name pattern given to `unzip` so that it is not expanded by your shell.

If you don't already have a list of files to be downloaded, but their names follow the pattern you gave, you can create a list as follows.

```
seq 0 99 | while read n; do echo "http://example.com/abcd-$n.zip"; done > filelist
```

Comment: `printf "http://example.com/abcd-%d.zip\n" {0..99}`